# How can I calculate the difference between two dates format Y/M/D h:m:s.ns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to subtract two dates, under the format Y-M-D hh:mm:ss, but i keep failing to get the result eventhough I found many solution close to my quest.
This is what i got so far :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',header=0)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Time']

import datetime as dt

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['Time']
#print(df['Time'])
s1 = df['Time'].head(1)
print(s1)
s2=df.iloc[-1,2]
print(s2)

format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
startDateTime = dt.datetime.strptime(s1, format)
endDateTime = dt.datetime.strptime(s2, format)

diff = endDateTime - startDateTime
```

I've tried the pd.to_datetime to convert it but I still get this error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Can you please help me overcome this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: what is the output of `print(s1)` and `print(s2)`...seems like from the error message that these variables aren't strings

Comment: s1=2018-12-05 10:54:05 and s2=2018-11-28 14:11:50
in my initial dataframe they are equal to s1= 2018/12/05 10:54:05.906224 and s2= 2018-11-28 14:11:50.871610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If convert column to datetimes, then no another conversation is necesary, only select values to scalars and subtract:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

startDateTime= df['Time'].iloc[0]
print(startDateTime)

#if 3rd column is filled by datetimes
endDateTime=df.iloc[-1,2]
print(endDateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to retrieve the first element of the df['Time'] series using the head() function which will not work. Try: s1 = df['Time'][0].

Essentially you are passing in a Pandas Series (s1) into the strptime function which expects a string.